# Assigning stdout to a FILE*

Tags: c, stdout

As code with global scope in a small C program I have:

```
FILE *outFile = stdout;
```

This is because I want to have `stdout` as the default destination for output but allow users to specify a different one on the command line (though I know they could just redirect I wanted belt and braces).

This fails to compile:

```
xmlheap.c:15:17: error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant
FILE *outFile = stdout;
            ^~~~~~
/usr/include/stdio.h:215:16: note: expanded from macro 'stdout'
#define stdout  __stdoutp
```

Is this not possible?

Comment: Why not just do this as an assignment early on in `main`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Static initializers in C have to be compile-time constants. Since `stdout` is not required to be such, you have to initialize the global variable in your dynamic program execution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE * outFile;

int main(void)
{
    outFile = stdout;

    /* ... */
}
```

(Specifically (cf. C11 7.21.1/3), `stdout` is mereley specified to be a macro that expands to an "expressions of type "pointer to `FILE`"".)

Answer (score 0):

Use `fdopen`:

```
   FILE *outFile = fdopen(1, "w");
```

Comment: Can you expand on your answer a little? For example, you could describe what the function arguments mean and how they achieve the assignment to `stdout`.

Comment: The return value of a function isn't a compile-time constant either.

Comment: @mafso I don't think `stdout` is a compile-time constant too.

Comment: @metacubed I thought it's not necessary since the function's pretty common: http://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen

Comment: Yes, which is OP's problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can define a macro :

```c
#define outFile stdout
```

Note that this doesn't copy the value of `stdout`, so if it changes for some reason, `outFile` will change as well.